# junit test to test save method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I use the following junit test to test save method, it works well and get 200 ok when test http status, I test that an entity is created, now I need test the created entity, test what it looks like. Can anyone help me please?

```
@Test   
public void testContact() throws Exception {
    long before = contactRepository.count();
    ContactResource r = new ContactResource();
    r.name = "name";
    r.email = "some-one@xxx.com";
    ResultActions perform = mockMvc.perform(
        post(ContactWebservice.URL)
            .content(r)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                
        ).andDo(print());
    long after = contactRepository.count();
    assertEquals("contact should be saved", before+1, after);
    perform.andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

method implementation

```
 @Override
 public void post(@RequestBody @Valid ContactResource resource){
    Contact registration = assembler.toEntity(resource);
    contactRepo.save(registration);
    Resource bodyR = loader.getResource(
        EuromakBackendConfig.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_CONTACT);
    String subject = "Thanks for registering";
    String html = support.toString(bodyR);      
    service.sendHtmlMail(from, registration.email, subject, html);
}
```

interface

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(@RequestBody ContactResource resource);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "test the created entity"? What do you need to test? What have you tried?